# how to use left formular in vba? how to determine active cells?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

How can I use left formula to get shorted string(eg: BC150033) in column B?
pic above is the result I used Left formula. however I want to use vba to achieve this same result.
I know use for each next loop however something is wrong..

```
      A                    B           
1  BC150033-001         BC150033
2  BR165522-002         BR165522
3   ect....



 Set SourceRange = Range(Sheets(2).Range("A1"), Selection.End(xlDown))
 For Each cell In SourceRange
If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit For

Sheets(2).Range("B" & cell.Row).Value = Left(cell.Value, 8)
Next
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the problem with Left. 
 Try this one, I changed the way how you get SourceRange.

```
Sub test()
    Set SourceRange = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
     For Each cell In SourceRange
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit For
        Range("B" & cell.Row).Value = Left(cell.Value, 8)
    Next
End Sub
```